# firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened called multiple times

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I called firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened on componentDidMount and removing it on componentWillUnmount() But seems like it never removes it as its registered multiple time when the app is removed from the background. Below is the code I used, Let me know what I'm doing wrong.

```
        notificationOpenedListener = firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened((notificationOpen: any) => {
        console.log("onNotificationOpened", notificationOpen);
        notificationOpen &&  notificationOpen.notification && notificationOpen.notification._data && notificationOpen.notification._data.extra && setTimeout(() => {
               }, 500);
    });

 async componentDidMount() {
        this.notificationOpenedListener = 
        firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened((notificationOpen: any) => {});
  }

componentWillUnmount() {
      this.notificationOpenedListener();
  }
```